# Possible to send generated serialkeys using HTTP and get one right?

Tags: http

I have hooked the WS2 library with C++ in a game and found it sends a request to the server using http to check if my serial key is valid. 
http://warbandmain.taleworlds.com/handlerservers.ashx?type=chkserial&serial=MBWB-????-????-????-????-????

My question is if I send requests with generated serial keys for lets say over a week would it possible I get one right? The server returns -1 if it is false and an id if it is right.

Note: I don't wish to steal serial keys to sell on ebay or something. I don't even want to try this but I was curious if it would be possible.

Comment: Yes, it could theoretically be possible. However, it is very likely that the website will block you / your IP address if you send an unusually high (and therefore suspicious) number of requests. You'd also have to generate & send _a lot_ of serials to have a chance of getting one right.

Comment: it doesn't already tried it the server doens't display a visible sign of blocking my ip or logging it in their sql database I can guess away 24/7 but could this be considered a cyber crime?

Comment: I wouldn't know if this is legal or not, so unfortunately I have no idea about that, sorry. It does depend a lot on your particular situation, where you are, local laws, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on this specific scenario as there are unknowns such as rate-limiting by the server (see comment by JonasCz), entropy of the serial keys, etc. Here is a general approach to considering this when protecting your own systems.

Each of the ? in the serial key can take one of a number of values as defined by an alphabet. For example, binary alphabet limits them to [0,1], hex limits them to [0-F], etc. The cardinality (c) of the alphabet is simply the number of options; binary = 2, hex = 16, and so on. There are 20 ? so, *best case* for protection, we have c^20 possible choices from which to guess (assuming a good entropy source for their original generation).

**Caveats**

- There are probably limitations on the actual choices in the form of checksums or authentication codes to validate a particular serial number. For example, the last 4 characters may be a truncated HMAC of the preceding ones, with security provided by the HMAC's key. There may simply be a non-cryptographic checksum which doesn't have a secret key.
- A variant of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) - we're not looking to match a specific serial number. There are a set of true serial numbers and a set of guessed ones; an intersection of these sets that is not empty is a success.

**Feasibility**

Once we have reduced the search space given the caveats we can assess the [feasibility of the brute-force attack with this excellent calculation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6NdQAAAAMAAJ&dq=&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=thermodynamic%20limitations). ("Thermodynamic Limitations" in Schneider B. Applied Cryptography pp. 157‐8).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but it will be a long process to bypass all the rate limits, per-IP limits, e.t.c. But occasionally you will hit it for sure.